# Android using JNI without static variables

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I created my own version of Android's MediaMetadataRetriever using the source code for MediaMetadataRetriever.java as the basis. My version uses FFmpeg to retrieve the metadata. This approach works however it relies on static variables in the C code to retain state in between JNI calls. This means I can only use one instance of this class at a time or the state can get corrupted. The two Java functions are defined as follows:

```
public class MediaMetadataRetriever
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("metadata_retriever_jni");
    }

    public MediaMetadataRetriever() {

    }

    public native void setDataSource(String path) throws IllegalArgumentException;
    public native String extractMetadata(String key);
```

}

The corresponding C (JNI) code code is:

```
const char *TAG = "Java_com_example_metadataexample_MediaMetadataRetriever";
static AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_metadataexample_MediaMetadataRetriever_setDataSource(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring jpath) {

    if (pFormatCtx) {
        avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
    }

    char duration[30] = "0";
    const char *uri;

    uri = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jpath, NULL);

    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, uri, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Metadata could not be retrieved");
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jpath, uri);
        jniThrowException(env, "java/lang/IllegalArgumentException", NULL);
        return;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Metadata could not be retrieved");
        avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);
        (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jpath, uri);
        jniThrowException(env, "java/lang/IllegalArgumentException", NULL);
        return;
    }

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jpath, uri);
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_metadataexample_MediaMetadataRetriever_extractMetadata(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jstring jkey) {

    const char *key;
    jstring value = NULL;

    key = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jkey, NULL) ;

    if (!pFormatCtx) {
        goto fail;
    }

    if (key) {
        if (av_dict_get(pFormatCtx->metadata, key, NULL, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)) {
            value = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, av_dict_get(pFormatCtx->metadata, key, NULL, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)->value);
        }
    }

    fail:
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jkey, key);

    return value;
}
```

Sample usage that outlines my issue would be:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource("one.mp3");

MediaMetadataRetriever mmr2 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
// This line resets the data source to two.mp3
mmr2.setDataSource("two.mp3");

// should retrieve the artist from one.mp3 but retrieves it from two.mp3 due to the static
// variable being reset in the previous statement       
String artist = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.ARTIST);
```

Can someone explain how I would structure this code so I could use multiple instances of MediaMetadataRetriever without them interfering with one another? I don't want to switch the code to C++ and I'm fairly certain I don't need to modify MediaMetadataRetriever.java since this code is taken line-for-line from the Android framework (which allows multiple instances, see example below). It appears I need to re-structure the C code but I'm unsure how to retain state across JNI calls without using a static variable. Thanks in advance.

```
File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Music/one.mp3");
File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Music/two.mp3");

android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(file1.toString());

android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr2 = new android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr2.setDataSource(file2.toString());

// Returns the artist of one.mp3, not two.mp3, as expected. This is the expected behavior
// and confirms that multiple instances of MediaMetadataRetriever can be used simultaneously
mmr.extractMetadata(android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
```

Comment: Make `setDataSource` return a `long` representation of the context pointer, then require that pointer in subsequent calls to `extractMetadata`.  You'll need an additional dispose function to get rid of the context when you're done.  Probably also makes sense to wrap that handling in a way to hide it from the consumer of `MediaMetadataRetriever` and maybe let GC handle the disposal via finalizer.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I had considered this, but how is it that Google is able to handle multiple instances without doing this? It appears their solution resides in the native (C) code.

Comment: Unless you somehow attach the context pointer to the `MediaMetadataRetriever` object (as a field or some hackery), you've got to store the context _somewhere_ in the native code.  You have to maintain the mapping between retriever object and context pointer; you can do that via some sort of mapping object, pthread locals, or something else - unfortunately C has no built-in map object.

Comment: AOSP code generally associates C-language objects with their Java-language counterparts by tucking the C pointer in a Java integer field, and then using a finalizer to clean up when the Java-language object gets GCed.  Most of the code uses `int` rather than `long`, which is all fun and games until pointers become 64 bits.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you or technomage provide me with a link to a working example? I'm still learning how to use JNI so I'm not fully grasping how I would store and reuse the pointer. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you please refer the code which makes you think that *"Android framework allows multiple instances"* ? And that means you want *simultaneously used*, not just *simultaneously existing* (which IS possible).

Comment: I edited the answer to include a code example that shows you can have two simultaneously used instances of Android's MediaMetadataRetriever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restructuring the code would be very straight forward. Instead of using `pFormatCtx` you simply extend the interfaces of the JNI calls so you can pass around the pointer you stored in `pFormatCtx` before. Now the big guestion is how to pass around the pointers while java doesn't know such a datatype? The most straight forward soulution would be to use ints (for 32 bit systems) or longs (for 64 bit systems) to passing pointers to and from the Java environment. Unfortunately you could get you a bit in hot water as soon as you switch between 64 and 32 bit versions of your library.

While I was trying to solve this problem some months ago I stumbled over an article of [Clebert Suconic](http://planet.jboss.org/post/pointers_in_jni_c). He pointed out a very elegant way for passing pointers safely through JNI without "hacking" around with typecasting. Instead he proposes to use `java.nio.ByteBuffer`.

The concept put in a nutshell is: He suggest to create a new ByteBuffer object of length zero: `env->NewDirectByteBuffer(myPointer, 0);` and pass the resulting jobject through the JNI back and forth.

The call `env->NewDirectByteBuffer(myPointer, 0);` creates a imutable byte buffer object pointing to the location you wanted to pass around. The fact that the buffer is imutable is perfect as you don't want to modify the memory location, you only want to store the location itself. What you get is an object encapsulating your pointer and you can leave the pointer size issues to the JVM.

**Edit:** Just for completeness: The pointer can later be retrieved calling `env->GetDirectBufferAddress(myPointer);`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a long field (or int if you know you'll only ever be on a 32-bit system) to store the native pointer, and to dispose of it in your object's finalizer when the object is GC'd.  From JNI, you can then save to that field the pointer obtained when you "open" your resource.

From the JNI manual:

> **Procedure for Accessing a Java Field**
>
> To get and set Java fields from a native method, you must do the
>   following:
>
> Obtain the identifier for that field from its class, name, and type
>   signature. For example, in FieldAccess.c, we have:
>
> `fid = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, cls, "si", "I");`
>
> and:
>
> `fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "s", "Ljava/lang/String;");`
>
> Use one of
>   several JNI functions to either get or set the field specified by the
>   field identifier. Pass the class to the appropriate static field
>   access functions. Pass the object to the appropriate instance field
>   access functions. For example, in FieldAccess.c, we have:
>
> `si = (*env)->GetStaticIntField(env, cls, fid);`
>
> and:
>
> `jstr = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, obj, fid);`
>
> Similar to calling a Java
>   method, we factor out the cost of field lookup using a two-step
>   process. The field ID uniquely identifies a field in a given class.
>   Similar to method IDs, a field ID remains valid until the class from
>   which it is derived is unloaded. Field Signatures
>
> Field signatures are specified following the same encoding scheme as
>   method signatures. The general form of a field signature is:
>
> `"field type"`
>
> The field signature is the encoded symbol for the type of
>   the field, enclosed in double quotes (""). The field symbols are the
>   same as the argument symbols in the method signature. That is, you
>   represent an integer field with "I", a float field with "F", a double
>   field with "D", a boolean field with "Z", and so on.
>
> The signature for a Java object, such as a String, begins with the
>   letter L, followed by the fully-qualified class for the object, and
>   terminated by a semicolon (;). Thus, you form the field signature for
>   a String variable (c.s in FieldAccess.java) as follows:
>
> `"Ljava/lang/String;"`
>
> Arrays are indicated by a leading square bracket
>   ([) followed by the type of the array. For example, you designate an
>   integer array as follows:
>
> `"[I"`
>
> Refer to the table in previous section which summarizes the
>   encoding for the Java type signatures and their matching Java types.
>
> You can use javap with option "-s" to generate the field signatures
>   from class files. For example, run:
>
> `> javap -s -p FieldAccess`
>
> This gives you output containing:
>
> ```
> ... 
> static si I 
> s Ljava/lang/String; 
> ...
> ```