# How to store a C variable (JNI) to a Java class instance

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

**Background**
My application has now reached a bottleneck where the slowest part of it is the AES encrypt and decrypt streams through which all data must pass. In order to overcome this I plan to implement this ciphering in native code via JNI and OpenSSL so that I may take advantage of things like AES-NI and direct memory access (my buffers are already direct, so I can already get a pointer to their memory region)

**The Issue**
It doesn't make sense to recreate the OpenSSL cipher with the key every time I need to cipher or decipher some data. If I were using Java I would simply store the Cipher instance as a field in the class, however since the cipher is a C "object", I can't do this.

**The Question**
How to tie a C "object" to a Java class instance, so that subsequent invocations can use the stored "object". I imagine this has something to do with storing the "object" pointer as a long into the Java class, and then dereferencing it, however I am not quite sure that this is entirely cross platform.

**The Answer**
Must be:

- Simplistic
- Fast
- Cross platform

Thanks for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'correct' way to store a native pointer inside a Java object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337268/what-is-the-correct-way-to-store-a-native-pointer-inside-a-java-object)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'd prefer the method I cited here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968547/android-using-jni-without-static-variables/15006577#15006577 over storing pointers as long integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable `private int mNativeObj` in Java Object, and a method to save native pointer, like `public void setNativeObject(int pointer)`. In C code, call `CallVoidMethod()` to save the pointer to Java Object. You can refer to [Oracle's doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4256).

Comment: Thanks, my main concern here though is shouldn't the pointer be a long (to account for 64 bit servers), would making it long then break 32 bit servers?

Comment: you're right. If consider about 64 bit, you should choose long

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing bulk data, I suggest using a direct ByteBuffer.  This is a window into native memory from Java. i.e. once you have written to the ByteBuffer it is already copied to native memory.  From C, you can get the address and use it as a pointer to memory which doesn't move.

If you just need cross OSes, but you are using an OpenJDK based JVM, you can use Unsafe to access native memory directly by address (just like a pointer).  I suggest you wrap this up in class(es) and test it thoroughly.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with my question. I've already stated that I'm using native buffers and have direct access to their memory address. What I NEED is a way to create a variable in C land, and store associate it with my Java object.

Comment: I suspect this is a bad idea.  You can do this, but I suggest you not.  This will complicate GCing as you have a reference from C to a Java object. If you discard this reference incorrectly, it will never be cleaned up.

Comment: I can assure you I am perfectly capable of managing the references. I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track of using a long in the java class to point to my C objects, however confirmation that this is indeed cross platform and that there isn't a better way would be nice.